# Android Studio не может найти пакет

Tags: android, android-studio

использую Android Studio сегодня обновил ее, выскочила ошибка,причем она выходит на любом модуле, даже пустом

> Installation did not succeed. The application could not be installed.
>   Installation failed due to:

```
cmd package install-create -r -t --full -S 1455676
```

> returns error 'Unknown failure:

```
cmd: Can't find service: package''
```

не понимаю,какой пакет не может найти.

Comment: так проблема с компиляцией или с установкой на эмулятор?

Comment: если со вторым то попробуйте открыть AVD Manager и запустить эмулятор через "Cold Boot Now"

Comment: проблема с компиляцией,не могу отрыть ни один проект,везде одно и то же пишет, так же при созжании нового проекта